# Syncing AD User with AD Groups

Tags: user-profile, active-directory, profile-sync

i want to create a ad connection in user profile service application, which sync specific users. These users are members of a group. When i check this group in the "AD Container" and start a full sync, none of the group members is synced. Question: How can i sync AD users without checking them directly in the "AD Container"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the OU, not the group.  You can use exclusion filters to define who not to select.  See this article below by Spence Harbar.

http://www.harbar.net/archive/2011/02/22/323.aspx

Comment: All Users in this AD are in the CN=Users Container. The User group i want to sync is in a OU. Even when i select this OU, none of the group members is synchronized.

Comment: Additionally you can review this post by the SP Escalation Team:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spses/archive/2011/05/31/sharepoint-2010-profile-sync-inability-to-import-users-based-on-group-membership.aspx

Comment: Thank you for this link, looks like syncing users via groups are not supported. Maybe one these options is applicable for my szenario.

Comment: I know it's a while after the fact but I'm still too much of a newbie here to up-vote; this q & a is very useful as it is the most clear-cut explanation and answer to what I'd think to be a common starting question re: AD sync and how SP handles groups and members (and how it's better to think in terms of OUs instead). You deserve a lot more up votes for this! Thanks.

Comment: @foocode: With a bit more  reputation, you will be able to [post comments everywhere](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment). Try answering a couple questions and you should get your rep up quickly. :)